# number hold by double container is greater than float even if values are equal

Tags: c, floating-point, double

```
main()
{

  float f=0.7;
  if(0.7>f)
  printf("Hi");
  else
  printf("Hello"):
}
```

When I compile this program output comes out to be `Hi`.

Can someone please explain the scenerio how `0.7>0.7` is `true`? Is this due to fact that `0.7` used in if statement is a `double` and `f` is a `float`?
Even if it is `double` still its value  is `0.7` difference created is just that in case of `double` it is stored in 8 byte while in case of `float` it is stored in 4 byte. But I think it does not matters how big is your container when the value stored in container is equal. So `0.7` can never be greater than f. So according to me it should result in `Hello`. then why `Hi` is the output?

Comment: There are hundreds of duplicates of this, with different float values. Long story short, since `0.7` cannot be represented exactly, and because `0.7` is treated as a `double`, not as a `float`, the two representations differ slightly, resulting in the behavior that you see. Change `0.7` to `0.7F` to make it work correctly. You wouldn't see this behavior with numbers that have an exact representation as `double` and `float`, for example, `0.5`, `0.25`, `0.125`, and so on.

Comment: http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf is strongly recommended to be read, at least first pages

Comment: can you please explain me a little more.i just change the value from 0.7 to 0.5 and yes you are right output comes out to be hello.

Answer (score 1):

The container does makes the difference here. The idea is how these values are stored and then retrieved. If you use a number that can be converted back to exact decimal value. You may see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use this and see the output:

```
 float f=0.7f;
```

If you define `float f = 0.7`, it is stored as `manttisa` and `exponent`. It depends on the `precision`. So in this case .7 will be `less than` .7. If you define `0.7f` it will be `equal` to `0.7`.

Comment: and if I take f=0.5 then output will be hello.why is 0.5 is not stored as mantissa and exponent.

Comment: @user3335653 you can represent `0.5 in binary as .10000000` and `.7 will be 0.1011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011`. It depends on how many bits are being used for `manttisa` and how many for `exponenet`. In `.7` if some of the `last bit` are not stored that will be less than `.7`, while it is not in the case of `.5`.